# Adding modules using System.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, systemjs

I installed `angular2-google-maps` to use for google maps in my Angular 2 application.

my `package.json` looks like this:

`{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server -c lite-server-conf.json",
    "typings": "typings",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "postinstall": "typings install && npm run tsc"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.14",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.6",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.1.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^1.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3 ",
    "sweetalert2": "1.3.2 ",
    "flexslider": "2.6.0 ",
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.9.0",
    "google-fonts": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings":"^0.7.12"
  }
}`

I then added the relevant modules to my `index.html` like this:

`<script src="node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBBiqOVDqRdhXharDKvO4Kx6DHMdzMvVn0" type="text/javascript"></script>`

My system.js configuraion:

```
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
System.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-google-maps': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },
    map: {
        "angular2-jwt": "node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js",
        "angular2-google-maps": "node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.js"
    }
});
System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
System.import('node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

To use the `angular2-google-maps` in my component I imported it as:

`import {ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES,} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';`

At first it threw the not found error(shown below) when I added the

`directives: [ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES]`

but after tweaking the
`system.js`
 configurations it was sorted.

I have a separate component `main.ts` that I do the bootstrapping in and I also added the module in it like this:
 imported it:

`import {ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS, NoOpMapsAPILoader, MapsAPILoader} from "angular2-google-maps/core";`

and

`bootstrap(AppComponent, [ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS,ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, FORM_PROVIDERS, BackendApis,
    provide(AuthHttp, {
        useFactory: (http) => {
            return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
                tokenName: 'jwt'
            }), http);
        },
        deps: [Http]
    }),
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
    provide(MapsAPILoader, {useClass: NoOpMapsAPILoader})
]);`

**Now my problem**

The map loads but only after I do reloads like two or three times of the page. my console debug throws this error:

`GET http://localhost:8003/node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.js/core.js 404 (Not Found)`

This is freaking bad for business cos in production I don't intend to tell users to keep reloading page(and I don't want to do it either!) so I was seeking to know, is my cofiguration ok?

I have tried to tinker with the `system.js` configurations till I got the map to load but it looks like I brought some serious bug along. Any optimizations or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: @manumoomoo no. i don't use angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

You actually helped me solve my issue.

It seems like you are mapping to a specific location, rather than to the path you actually need when you import google maps.

Just change:

```
"angular2-google-maps": "node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.js"
```

to:

```
"angular2-google-maps": "node_modules/angular2-google-maps"
```

Also you could also remove the line and I'm sure it'll work as the paths generally default to node_modules on import.